# Algorithms for computing Nash equilibria

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Excuse me, since I am modeling a situation into a nonzero-sum n-player non-cooperative game. I wonder if there is any algorithm for computing its Nash equilibria?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search, something that I highly suggest you do before asking questions here, and found [this](http://www.uwyo.edu/shogren/jaysho/nashnotes.pdf). It gives a step-by-step for computing the equilibria. [Here's another](http://www.cs.upc.edu/~ia/nash51.pdf) discussing non-cooperative games.

Comment: This is only for NE in pure strategy. Things get more complicated when computing NE in mixed strategy. But thank you, I've found some algorithms.